# Sending image along other data in ajax to php

Tags: php, ajax

I need little help. I created ajax form and pass the data to the api.php. I have no problem sending normal value to the php. I currently facing problem on sending file through.

***HTML***

```
<form id="adding" enctype="multipart/form-data">

 <input type="file" id="imgInp">

 <input type="text" id="name">

 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default pull-right">Submit</button>
</form>
```

***Javascript***

```
$('#adding').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: 'api.php?do=add',
       data: {
            img: $("#imgInp").val(),
            name: $("#name").val()
        },
       success: function(data)
       {
          if (data === 'KO'){
            document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "Alert";           
          }
           if (data === 'OK'){
            document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "OK";          
          }
       }
   });
```

Data from variable name can be send but not from img. Please help. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you need to use the form data object. In the data attribute, via your ajax call,

FYI: you need to have jquery libraries to get this working

This would grab all form contents and then you can receive theform contents including the image on your php controller

```
    $('#adding').submit(function(e) {
 var formData = new FormData($(this));
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: 'api.php?do=add',
           data: formData ,
          contentType: false,
          processData: false,
            cache: false,
           success: function(data)
           {
              if (data === 'KO'){
                document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "Alert";           
              }
               if (data === 'OK'){
                document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "OK";          
              }
           }
       });
```

On your php side,

```
<?php
try{
if(isset($_FILES) && $_FILES['tmp_name'] != null){
//awesome, we have something here
//then check for extensions, validate and move upload 
}else{
  //no file
}

}catch(Exception $ex){
  echo($ex->getMessage());
}
?>
```

Comment: thanks man, on the php site, still few question to ask. the variable will be what? $_POST[?array?]

Comment: Use the $_FILES[] array. this would grab it.  Read more http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp  When you make this ajax call, it gets all form contents. Then by using the $_FILES, you get the files that were being sent(images, pdfs,etc). I will update my answer